# What Graphical LIbrary should I use for C

Tags: c, user-interface

I want to make a project in C using GUI on windows. What are all the graphical libraries I can use and which one is the best. I have tried windows.h and SPL(stanfords portable Library).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that questions of the kind "which one is best" or "which one should I use" is not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: BTW, if you are a student, I invite you to install GNU/Linux on your laptop, since Linux is mostly free software, whose source code you could study (and contribute to). Also, Linux has *lots* of good free software developer tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you want to code something [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) to other [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (notably GNU/[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), which I invite you to install on your laptop) or not. If you are developing a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (and wants to get some external contributions) and/or care about [software portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability), you may want to use a cross-platform toolkit like [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/), [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/), [libsfml](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) etc..

If C++ is an option, consider also [Qt](http://qt.io/)

I am not sure that enumerating *all* graphical libraries (or [widget toolkits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widget_toolkit)) makes any sense. Very probably, there exist a lot of proprietary (or even open source) obscure ones.